# I am not able to retrieve the list of data from the dataBase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**My Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("findFlights")
public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to,
        @RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="MM-dd-yyyy") Date departureDate,
        ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findFlights(from, to, departureDate);

    modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);
    return "displayFlights";

}
```

}

**MyRepository**

```
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {

@Query("from Flight where departureCity=:departureCity and arrivalCity=:arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture=:dateOfDeparture")

List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from, @Param("arrivalCity") String to,
        @Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
```

}

**MyEntity**

```
@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity{
private String flightNumber;
private String operatingAirlines;
private String departureCity;
private String arrivalCity;
private Date dateOfDeparture;
private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
// Getters and Setters
```

**Issue**
I am not able to get the list of flights from the DB even when my DB has the required combination of data for:
`List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findFlights(from, to, departureDate);`

but flights list is always blank (flights[])

Answer (score 0):

this method will replace the above query

```
 List<Flight> findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(String from,String to,Date departureDate)
```

or

try using **Like** or **%** in your Hql query.

Answer (score 0):

For custom query you can use jpql

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Flight f WHERE f.departureCity = ?1 and f.arrivalCity = ?2 and f.dateOfDeparture = ?3")
List<Flight> findFlight(String from, String to, Date departureDate);
```

You should annotate Entity class with @Column annotation